# Python (Django) get and encode params from url

Tags: python, django, query-string

I have a query string like this:

```
main.php?location=%D0%E0%E7%E4%EE%F0%FB&page=04rent&way=1&filtr=1
```

when i'am trying to get location value:
location = request.GET['location'], my value is `u'\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\'`

What should i do to get the same characters from the query string?

Answer (score 0):

Put the correct charset the query string is encoded in into [`request.encoding`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.encoding) and try again.

Comment: can you give me an example?